# UDP Server for Hololens using Unity 5.5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, udp, hololens

I have some serious issues getting UDP working for Hololens. I have a UDP client that sends data to Hololens' IP however I have the exact same issue as this guy: 
   https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/comment/9837#Comment_9837

Although his solution uses async and async gives the error just like the comment mentioned below it: 
doesn't support c# 4.

I used to use UDPclient for other devices but looks like Hololens requires different set up.

Upon some thorough search on the net, I noticed loads of people have this issue so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: It says you should use `UNITY_EDITOR` around `async`. What don't you understand about that?

Comment: I didn't say I don't understand it. I said it doesn't work. async requires .net 4.5 but unity doesn't support that @Programmer

Comment: It doesn't work on the Editor. It works on Halolens.

Comment: Also, post your code.